# number of functions >$g:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ least one $x\in\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

> Let $f:\left\{1,2,3\right\}\rightarrow \left\{1,2,3\right\}$ be a function. Then the number of functions
>
> $g:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for at least one $x\in\{1,2,3\}$.

$\bf{Options}::$ $(a)\;\;\; 11\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\;\; 19\;\;\;\;\; (c)\;\;\; 23\;\;\;\;\; (d)\;\; 27$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If $f:A=\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow B= \{1,2,3\}\;,$

Then Total number of function from $A$ to $B $ is $ = 3^3 = 27.$

Now I did not understand How can I proceed further

Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Take the $3^3$ functions that take arbirtrary values and subtract the $2^3$ functions that avoid $f$.

Comment: Thanks  Hagen von Eitzen But I did not Understand How we can Subtract $2^3$ from total function. Plz explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said,the total number of functions $g:A \rightarrow B$ is 27. Count the funtions that do not satisfy your requirements,that is count how many $g:A \rightarrow B$ such that $g(x) \neq f(x) \forall x \in A$. It is easy to see that you have for every $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ 2 choices for $g(i)$: the two numbers that are different from $f(i)$. Then you have $2^3$ functions g not satisfying the condition and $27-8=19$ correct functions.

Comment: Thanks Nicolò Ruggeri, as you say  $f(x)\neq g(x)\forall x \in \{1,2,3\}$. Total number of such functon is $=8,$ (Can You explain in detail.)

Comment: Just a matter of counting. Suppose f(1)=2 , f(2)=3,f(3)=1. Then you can have g(1)=1 or g(1)=3. The same goes for g(2),g(3), You have two independent choices for three times, then a total of $2^3$ choices

Comment: Like if we take $f(1) = 1\;,$ Then $g(1),g(2),g(3)\in \{2,3\}$. So Total function from $g:{1,2,3}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ is $ = 2^3$ Similarly for $f(2)\neq 2$ and $f(3)\leq 3$. So we Get Total $8+8+8 = 24$ function.

Comment: If f(1)=1 then just $g(1) \in \{1,2,3\}$. Then g(2)$\in \{1,2,3\} $ but $\neq{f(2)}$ and the same for f(3)